# Strange input rendering issue in blade for Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having the following code in a blade:

```
                @if ($selectedChapter ?? '')
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedChapter" name="selectedChapter" value="{{$selectedChapter->id}}">
                @endif
                @if ($question ?? '')
                <input type="hidden" id="questionId" name="questionId" value="{{$question->id}}"> 
                @endif
                <input type="hidden" id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="@if(isset($answer_id)){{$answer_id}}@endif">  
                <input type="hidden" id="wrong" name="wrong" value="@if(isset($wrong)){{$wrong}}@endif">
                <input type="hidden" id="first" name="first" value="{{$first ?? ''}}"> 
                <input type="hidden" id="firstQuestion" name="firstQuestion" value="{{$firstQuestion ?? ''}}">  
                <input type="hidden" id="lastQuestion" name="lastQuestion" value="{{$lastQuestion ?? ''}}">
```

For some reason, the fields are not rendering correctly. What happens is that every other field is rendering. That its that the selectedChapter, answer_id, first and lastQuestion fields are rendering.

If i change the order of the fields, the same thing happens but in different order. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course... The issue was the iCheck jquery plugin and more specifically a selector. I made some modifications yesterday and changed the selector from input.line to input. That had as a result to select more input fields that it was supposed to. Anyway now its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the validation for every value, too much `isset` and the `??` isn't needed.

In blade views, when you need to set a value for input, you retrieve that from a source, blade automatically validate if that value is null or empty, if not, it won't show anything.

This should work:

```
@if($selectedChapter)
   <input type="hidden" id="selectedChapter" name="selectedChapter" value="{{$selectedChapter->id}}">
@endif
@if($question)
   <input type="hidden" id="questionId" name="questionId" value="{{$question->id}}"> 
@endif
   <input type="hidden" id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="{{ $answer_id }}">  
   <input type="hidden" id="wrong" name="wrong" value="{{ $wrong }}">
   <input type="hidden" id="first" name="first" value="{{ $first }}"> 
   <input type="hidden" id="firstQuestion" name="firstQuestion" value="{{ $firstQuestion }}">  
   <input type="hidden" id="lastQuestion" name="lastQuestion" value="{{ $lastQuestion }}">
```

Comment: If I dont check for the variables, I receive "undefined variable" errors. Even removing all kinds of checks, is showing the same behaviour. Moving the fields anywhere in the blade also does the same. This is extremely frustrating :O

Comment: Are you sending the variables into the view? normally using `compact('variable')` or something.

Comment: Thanks but I found the issue. Since it was working before, I checked some changes I did yesterday and I found the issue.

Comment: Perfect, next time you encounter a similar problem, add these jquery plugin details to the question, maybe some people think is not relevant, but it is.